# drag and drop animation VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, animation, drag-and-drop

I'm learning how to deal with drag&drop javascript events.

i created a simple grid that filled with objects from array, and its possible to change the positions of the items by drag and drop them:

```js
var icons=[
  {order:1,name:"tel",bg:'red'},
  {order:2,name:"facebook",bg:'green'},
  {order:3,name:"whatsup",bg:'blue'},
  {order:4,name:"waze",bg:'yellow'},
  {order:5,name:"gallery",bg:'purpule'},
  {order:6,name:"insta",bg:'grey'}
];


function rendericons(icons)
{
  var zone=document.getElementById("icons");
  var sorticons = icons.slice(0);
  sorticons.sort(function(a,b) {return a.order - b.order; });
  var html="";
  for(var x in sorticons)
  { 
    html+="<span style='background-color:"+sorticons[x]['bg']+"' id='"+sorticons[x]['order']+"' draggable='true'>"+sorticons[x]['name']+"</span>";
  }
  zone.innerHTML=html;
}

rendericons(icons);



document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
  event.target.style.opacity = "0.4";
});

document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {

  
});

// Output some text when finished dragging the p element and reset the opacity
document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
  event.target.style.opacity = "1";
});

/* Events fired on the drop target */

// When the draggable p element enters the droptarget, change the DIVS's border style
document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {

});

// By default, data/elements cannot be dropped in other elements. To allow a drop, we must prevent the default handling of the element
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

});

// When the draggable p element leaves the droptarget, reset the DIVS's border style
document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {

});

/* On drop - Prevent the browser default handling of the data (default is open as link on drop)
   Reset the color of the output text and DIV's border color
   Get the dragged data with the dataTransfer.getData() method
   The dragged data is the id of the dragged element ("drag1")
   Append the dragged element into the drop element
*/
document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var itemtoreplace=event.target.id;
    replaceitems(data,itemtoreplace);

});


function replaceitems(data,itemtoreplace)
{
  if(itemtoreplace!="icons"){

//event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
//console.log(data);
var beforeindex=0;
var replaceindex=0;
for(x in icons)
{
  if(icons[x]['order']==data)
  beforeindex=x;

  if(icons[x]['order']==itemtoreplace)
  replaceindex=x;
}

icons[beforeindex]['order']=itemtoreplace;
icons[replaceindex]['order']=data;
rendericons(icons);

  }
}
```

```css
.icons {
margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap:20px;
}

.icons span {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
  <div id="icons" class="icons droptarget"></div>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/DavidiAllove/pen/PoGwRwg

It works great, but i like to add animations to the drag and drop event, like that:
[gif example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0x0S.gif)

anyone that can help me? thanks.

Comment: It looks like the animation in your gif is maybe created using a different technique.  Making the dragging item follow the mouse via something like: "transform: translate( `${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px). The other items' top position changes depending on if the item following the mouse is over them. Javascript.info has some good starting tutorials for similar techniques.